# openssl_sign and "supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key"

Tags: php, openssl, certificate, key, sign

I have problem with the function `openssl_sign` because return this error

> Warning: openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key ...

This is my code and I hope for your help:

```
<?php
    $debug=true; 
    $data=file_get_contents(realpath("C:/Users/User/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/server.key"));
    $doc=file_get_contents(realpath("C:/Users/User/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/docum.docx"));
    echo $debug ? $data : '';
    $priv_key = openssl_pkey_get_private( $data );
    $sign="";
    $digitalS=openssl_sign ($doc,$sign, $priv_key);
?>
```

I have created the certificate and private key with openssl , now I would like to sign the document... What's wrong with this code ?

Comment: [Cannot sign anything with PHP openssl_sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8672177), [Supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key using Google Private Key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21149200), [openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22609016), and friends...